# File Channel reads/adds wrong data

Tags: java, udp, bytebuffer, datagram, filechannel

I am using a filechannel with a byte buffer to send packets over the network. My problem is that when the filechannel reads the last few bytes it appends the last bit of data from previous bytes read even though I am clearing the byte buffer after I write.

For example,

Byte Buffer size = 512 
For the last iteration, the remaining bytes to send is 372.
It reads the last 372 but it also appends another 140 bytes (512-372) to the end of it, and appears that last 140 bytes is from the previous 512 bytes sent.

Heres my code:

```
ByteBuffer bBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);

while (fChannel.read(bBuffer) > 0) {

    bBuffer.flip();
    datagramChannel.write(bBuffer);
    bBuffer.clear();

    //omitted code
}
```

Comment: @Fildor So is there another way to handle this situation, without clear

Comment: this code looks correct.  my guess is the bug lies elsewhere.  are you getting the extra bytes in the datagram consumer?  if so, show your consumer code.

Comment: @Fildor - ByteBuffers contain all that info, you don't need to do that (and in fact, there is no such method).

Comment: @Fildor I was thinking I could set a value equal to fChannel.read(bBuffer) then create a byte buffer with that particular size and set it equal to my old byte buffer

Comment: @user3339242 - you would be wasting your time with that.  can you answer the question in my first comment?

Comment: @jtahlborn On the receiving side it says it is receiving 372 bytes which is what I expect

Comment: then i am confused as to where you are seeing the "extra" bytes?

Comment: @jtahlborn it says it receives the correct number of bytes but the data in the text file repeats at the end

Comment: _what_ text file?  again, if this is the consumer side, then you should _show that code_.

Comment: @Fildor when I use that write method it says ByteBuffer cannot be converted to ByteBuffer[]?

Comment: @jtahlborn The FileChannel has a text file attached to it before reading into the bytebuffer

Comment: the FileChannel that you are reading from?  The file on disk has extra bytes in it?

Comment: Forget my comment jtahlborn is right.

Comment: @jtahlborn When I read in the last few bytes remaining in the , it gives me 372 but it still sends it like there is 512 bytes by appending the last few bytes.

Comment: Do you do anything else with that buffer than shown in the question?

Comment: @jtahlborn on the receiver side I am calling the bytebuffer.remaining() method to get the number of bytes I am receiving, on the sender side I am using bytebuffer.position() to get the amount I am sending

Comment: Are you calling position() _afer_ you call clear()?

Comment: @jtahlborn I call position before I writer and after I flip. So before clear

Comment: call `remaining()` after you flip and before you write to determine how many bytes you will write.

Comment: also, in future questions, don't omit the relevant code.

Comment: @jtahlborn Changed it to remaining() and It still says sending out 374 bytes

Comment: isn't that what it is supposed to say...?

Comment: Yes ok so heres the issue: in my textfile I have sentence 45 sentence 46 sentence 47 and last sentence. In the second to last packet it sends sentence 45, then in the last packet it sends sentence 46,47, the last sentence and the last 140 bytes it sends the last part of sentence 45

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65101/discussion-between-user3339242-and-jtahlborn).

Comment: i'm pretty sure in your previous comment, you indicated that the datagram consumer was receiving the correct data.  if that's not the case, then the problem is probably in your consumer.  if that is the case, then i fail to see why you say "i'm sending incorrect data but the consumer is receiving correct data"?

Comment: @jtahlborn I explained it more in the chat

Comment: unfortunately, you are not explaining it in a meaningful way.  i would suggest sitting down with a debugger and determining _exactly_ where the problem is, then see if you can fix it.  if not, put _all_ the details into a new question, and then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using a `DatagramChannel` this way is really never going to work. You're just sending chunks of the file which may or may not arrive, or arrive twice, or more, in any order. Use TCP.
2. Even if it does magically work, and I have my suspicions that there are further bugs in the 'omitted code', or the receiving code:

   ```
   while (fChannel.read(bBuffer) > 0) {

       bBuffer.flip();
       datagramChannel.write(bBuffer);
       bBuffer.clear();

       //omitted code
   }
   ```

   The correct version of the copy loop between channels in Java is as follows:

   ```
   while (fChannel.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0) {    
       buffer.flip();
       datagramChannel.write(bBuffer);
       buffer.compact();
   }
   ```

   Note that you must continue writing while there is still anything in the buffer (`buffer.position() > 0`), and that you must `compact()` rather than `clear()` so as not to assume that the `write()` emptied the buffer.
3. If it wasn't a `DatagramChannel` you should use a buffer much larger than 512, for example 8192.